# How to make Firebase Auth accept Hash fragment URL?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Question**: I am finding a solution for Firebase Auth to accept Hash fragment URL so that redirect can be done correctly.

**Scenario:** I am using Firebase Auth to authenticate user by Email link and I set the `url` in the `ActionCodeSettings` = `http://localhost:52751/#/authentication` for my local testing.

The `FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail()` is successfully called and a mock email link is created in Firebase Emulator with all required parameters: `http://127.0.0.1:9099/emulator/action?mode=signIn&lang=en&oobCode=HhpkI2RVTaUjAXAyahgLqL53Lmgy7MovYuDxKtZwq995LQrL4ieKkN&apiKey=fake-api-key&continueUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A52751%23%2Fauthentication`

However, when the link above is called, the actual callback omits `#/authentication` and  append all parameters to the default root route `http://localhost:52751/?mode=signIn&lang=en&oobCode=iTTzzcvuvNuu661DU-jv6qAo1NHcrZ3Wr7dSuR3eqTP-pSlx_P8WW7&apiKey=fake-api-key`

Since I am using Flutter, the workaround I found is to use `usePathUrlStrategy();` and set the `url` in `ActionCodeSettings` to `http://localhost:52751/authentication` (i.e. to use path URL without `/#`) After this setting, Firebase Auth redirect to the authentication widget with the correct path `http://localhost:52751/authentication?mode=signIn&lang=en&oobCode=iQKFTRuYJuBm87cOJAF1HUCibbPpfdxDATaRdKyJ4Bzv--9MRYrcwJ&apiKey=fake-api-key`.

I would like to stick with the Flutter default Hash URL Strategy because it's been supported by all browser, vs Path Strategy which is not as popular in terms of browser compatibility. Is Firebase Auth support such redirect?

Comment: In the continue URL you are missing a slash:

The output from the continueUrl encoded is: http://localhost:52751#/authentication and it should be http://localhost:52751/#/authentication

so the continueUrl should really read : http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A52751%2F%23%2Fauthentication

Comment: What platform are you testing this on? Is it flutter web?

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderN., I actually tried both. But in either case, Firebase Auth cuts everything after "#". I further confirmed with Firebase that hash URL is not supported by Firebase and they support only Path URL Strategy. Yes, this is for Flutter web and it's ironic that the default for Flutter web is the reverse.